# Get all stored procedures where table is being used in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need the query or code in SQL Server to get all the stored procedures in which table is being used in the server (need all stored procedures in all databases on that server).

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.procedures 
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%[dbo].[Batch]%.
```

Above query will give in the current database but I need the query to get from all the databases in that server.

Thanks. Sandeep

Comment: Then you will need to run that query on all the databases on your server. Here is a great article explaining one way to do this. https://sqlblog.org/2018/10/22/sp-ineachdb-2 What about other servers? Do you access this table through link servers too?

Comment: Google 'SQL SERVER referenced entities'

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select * from sysobjects where id in 
(select id from syscomments where text like '%myquery%')
order by [name]
```

where "myquery" is the name of the table. You need to run this on each database on the server individually.

Comment: Thanks for the query but this query is giving me system procedures also.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
"USE [?]; SELECT * FROM sys.procedures WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%[dbo].[Batch]%'"
```

Just consider your permutations of the code that references the Batch object (dbo.batch, [dbo].[batch], dbo.[batch], etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried above query which you posted but this one is giving all other SP in which the table is not used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I got that below query will give all Stored Procedures that are dependent on any table or view for all the databases in the server.

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)

 SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + quotename(NAME, '''') + ' AS Db_Name, Routine_Name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as SP_Name FROM ' + quotename(NAME) + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines WHERE ROUTINE_Definition like ''%Replace_Table_Name_Here%'' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = ''PROCEDURE''' FROM sys.databases ORDER BY NAME FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '')

 EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL
```